# How do you copy all the commands and its process files in cmd?

Tags: cmd

Today, I did a few mistakes in my git command which I did it at the command prompt.

Now, this command actually led to thousand lines of codes in the process as the command process whatever it needs to process.

But, I wanted to examine where I had done wrongly.

Since the lines runs to more than 1k lines, even if I did Ctrl Alt A, it would not able to select all.

Another attempt I tried is doskey /history > output.txt but it only gives me all the git commands and not the files it has processed after each command I made.

Therefore, I would like to ask what can I do in order to copy all the git commands I had made and the files it has processed from the beginning till the end ?

OS : Windows 10 (can't reply the below comment so I just add in here - I am using cmd.exe)

Comment: This is not exactly a code question. Are you in a git/bash shell or at a cmd.exe prompt?

Comment: Now then I can add the command. It is cmd.exe

Comment: If you still have the `cmd.exe` window open, you can copy the text from the window using Ctrl-M, then hold down Shift and use the Up-Arrow to select the text. Press Enter to copy to the clipboard. I do not know what Shift-Alt-C does. This is really more of a https://superuser.com/ question. Please do not be surprised if it gets closed.

Comment: PowerShell has `Start-Transcript` and `Stop-Transcript` commands that will keep a log of everything that happens. In a PowerShell console, use the command `help Start-Transcript -Full` to see what it does. You could open a PowerShell console, Start-Transcript, start a cmd.exe console, and have it recorded in the transcript file.

Comment: thanks. I have since closed the windows.  But, thanks. I will carry out an experiment on my laptop. @lit but will Ctrl-M enable me to see the front part of the long text ? cos when I scrolled manually to the "top" - it is not the top  or beginning part at all.